# Passing php Variables to jQuery flot piechart

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, flot

I have 3 variables defined in php

```
$record = "283-161-151";
$rec = explode("-", $record);
$win = $rec[0];
$draw = $rec[1];
$loss = $rec[2];
```

$win, $draw and $loss echo fine, so I know they are working

When setting the var data in a separate js file which runs at the foot of the page, I want to pass the 3 variables to 3 set text labels.

```
var data = [
{ label: 'Wins',  data: '<?php echo $win ?>', color:'green'},
{ label: 'Draws',  data: '<?php echo $draw ?>', color:'orange'},
{ label: 'Losses',  data: '<?php echo $loss ?>', color:'red'}
];
```

If I change each of the js php calls from `<?php echo $win ?>` to the actual number for testing the chart shows.

I wonder if the inline php syntax is correct? I have tried a couple of different formats, hoping its an easy fix with a fresh pair of eyes.

### Update

php code

```
<?php
$record = "283-161-151";
$rec = explode("-", $record);
?>
<script>
 var win = <?php echo $rec[0]; ?>;
 var draw = <?php echo $rec[1]; ?>;
 var loss = <?php echo $rec[2]; ?>;
</script>
```

js file code

```
var data = [
{ label: 'Wins',  data: var win, color:'green'},
{ label: 'Draws',  data: var draw, color:'orange'},
{ label: 'Losses',  data: var loss, color:'red'}
];
```

When I look at page source I see this

```
<script>
 var win = 283;
 var draw = 161;
 var loss = 151;
</script>
```

But still no output.. if I replace var win, var draw etc in the final js file with numbers it does work..

anyone know if I am getting close? Cheers

Comment: If I'm reading your question correctly... you are trying to output 3 PHP variables in another file than the file where you have set the variables?

Comment: The script is included in the php file so it is the same file is it not :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that you are quoting the numbers.  Change it so that the numbers are unquoted:

```
var data = [
{ label: 'Wins',  data: <?php echo $win ?>, color:'green'},
{ label: 'Draws',  data: <?php echo $draw ?>, color:'orange'},
{ label: 'Losses',  data: <?php echo $loss ?>, color:'red'}
];
```

Comment: cheers.. I tried that too but still nothing.. its doing my head in now lol

Comment: It might help if you added the javascript as it is outputted (i.e. after it reaches the browser).

Comment: I have done.. everything works as expected until I add the variables to call the data instead of static data, the data is prepared and available before javascript loads, but whatever code I try it doesn't populate.

Answer (score 0):

Evidently your PHP variables are outside of the scope, that is because echo returns ''.

There is a good topic describing " [How to define a variable in JavaScript with PHP echo function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734338/how-to-define-a-variable-in-javascript-with-php-echo-function/13734383#13734383) "

P.S.: For testing purpose if it is possible you may try to embed javascript snippet into PHP-script where variables are declared.

Comment: echo returns the values I expect, I have placed the script in tags after the variables and the div call is placed below the script tags. but still not rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to run php in a javascript file. The browser can not process server code. php runs on server only.

What you can do is pass the php variable to a javascript variable as follows:
Within page ( prior to script tag for external script):

```
$record = "283-161-151";
$rec = explode("-", $record);
echo '<script>var plotData='.json_encode($rec).';</script>';
/* displays var plotData=[283,161,151]; */
```

Now using the javascript variable that already exists JS will be:

```
var data = [
{ label: 'Wins',  data: plotData[0], color:'green'},
{ label: 'Draws',  data: plotData[1], color:'orange'},
{ label: 'Losses',  data: plotData[2], color:'red'}
];
```

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for clearing that up! I have modified the code to represent the above, but its still not displaying the chart :(

Comment: any errors in browser console? That is always first check and gives a lot of clues

Comment: I can see the data has been set as expected.. there is a define error in the next script, since adding it directly into the php file above the div id call, probably something to do with the main jquery files not loading until afterwards as they are all in the footer, i will work that out and get back - cheers

Comment: I have stripped everything back, so only required jquery and flot files present, changed the order, so jquery 1st, flot 2nd, the execute inline script tags for plotData and then the actual Pie Chart Script, not showing any errors now, but still nothing displayed.. when I do a view source on the page i see - <script>var plotData=["283","161","151"];</script> - which led me believe that the data has been organised and set correctly.. cheers

Comment: basics work, although not enough data points for a line graph  http://jsfiddle.net/5gKWG/ Must be something else wrong

Comment: Now that is odd! I have forked and put the exact sample code I am working with, where it works on my test page - it doesn't work in jfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/TmybY/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TmybY/1/ - missing js libraries.. I have added them and now the test environment there works..

Comment: Ok.. It works exactly as I expect when data var is set as follows:  var data = [{ label: "Internet Explorer",  data: 12},{ label:"Mobile",  data: 27},{ label: "Safari",  data: 85}];However when I change it to this var data = [{ label: 'Wins',  data: plotData[0], color:'green'},
{ label: 'Draws',  data: plotData[1], color:'orange'},
{ label: 'Losses',  data: plotData[2], color:'red'}
]; after including the php info it stops working with no hint or error of why.. Page Source after the page has fully loaded shows -    <script>var plotData=["283","161","151"];</script>